# Accessing E-Commerce and subscribers through Rest API - Sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity

Have been trying to retrieve both the subscribers/customers and their ecommerce interactions from a sitefinity CMS site through Rest API. I'm having a trial version and tried the below options for connecting the same,

1. Not able to access via Data Experience Cloud API as by using the trial version account it is throwing invalid user credentials. (I want to know whether for testing it do we need actual license for the same?)
   [image]
2. Have mentioned we can create our own web service for exposing it outside through admin portal but still it list out only the CMS contents not the ecommerce data and all as in attached image [image]

Please guide me with suggestions on the same

Comment: Can you rephrase the question and make it a bit more clear?

Comment: @VeselinVasilev : Thanks for the quick response and i hope the question is clear now

Answer (score 1):

For the DEC part - you will have to ask Progress Telerik Sales people to activate an account (data center) for you. Then you should be able to connect to your data center.

The built-in Web Services module in Sitefinity does not expose any eCommerce services (as of v.11).

So, you can build your own web api (or service stack) service returning data using the Sitefinity's API.

You can start from here: https://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-query-orders